# Intel i965 and compiz in 11.04 64-bit

Tags: 11.04, compiz, graphics, intel

I would like to know if my Intel i965 card can use Compiz effects. I heard it was blacklisted and needed a fix by `xorg`. Is the fix available in 64-bit 11.04? I'm a new Windows migrant, so take it easy on me.

**Update**

I know it is going to be released in April, so I'm digging around for hardware compatibility issues. Does that mean when the 11.04 when it is released, I can use Compiz? Also I tried 10.10 Netbook live USB and appearance window showed that 'Mutter isn't working'. Finally, I plan to buy a modem, can it work out of box or will I need to tweak something, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to strongly advise not to get started with Ubuntu using version 11.04. As the name suggests it will be released in next month. Therefore today this is not a stable release but only a development alpha version. It is not thought be be used by end users on there production machines but for testing only. Therefore you will only be unsatisfied with it and this serves nobody.

Thus, please stick with either the latest stable version 10.10 or 10.04 which is the most recent version with an extended support time. However I advise you to install 10.10 as you can easily upgrade later when 11.04 is released and therefore stable and safe to use.

To answer your initial question, there should not be any problem with your intel card and compiz as far as I know, however there has just been implemented a big change in the development version which is making problem in 11.04 only, this does not affect the stable version.

Hope I could help you! Have fun with Ubuntu!